# When using Handsontable how to force a selected cell into edit mode?

Tags: jquery-plugins, handsontable

Handsontable provides some nice hooks for when a cell is selected but I can't seem to figure out way to get it to allow me to force a cell into edit mode when it has been selected.

I can detect the cell selection like this:

```
Handsontable.PluginHooks.add( 'afterSelection', function( row, column ) {
    var current_td = this.getCell( row, column );
});
```

And from there I can even obtain the cell element that was selected.  But from there I can't seem to trigger the cell into edit mode (where it has an actively selected textarea field inside of it).  This is normally triggered by a double click.  Doing the obvious doesn't seem to work:

```
Handsontable.PluginHooks.add( 'afterSelection', function( row, column ) {
    var current_td = this.getCell( row, column );

    $(current_td).dblclick();
});
```

Anyone else ever done this or have thoughts on how I might get it to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And I believe I've answered my own question:

```
Handsontable.PluginHooks.add( 'afterSelectionEnd', function() { 
        f2_event = $.Event( 'keydown', { keyCode: 113 } );
        this.$table.trigger(f2_event);
});
```

That seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I had to put the f2 trigger inside a setTimeout in order to make this work because firing it right away seems to cause a null error inside handsontable.  firing it after a delay puts it at the end of the event chain and seems to work

Answer (score 11):

For anyone intersted in this question, now there is a better programmable way to achieve the same result.

```
this.selectCell(row, col);
this.getActiveEditor().beginEditing();
```

This selects the `(row, col)` cell and enters edit mode (i.e. same as double click or pressing F2/Enter).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit Mode on click:**

```
afterSelectionEnd: function (r, c, r2, c2) {
  if (r == r2 && c == c2) {
     getActiveEditor().beginEditing();
     getActiveEditor().enableFullEditMode();   
  }
}
```

When you add enableFullEditMode();
caret moves in the cell while pressing left or right button instead of jump to another cell.

**Anaother example: only first row:**

```
afterSelectionEnd: function (r, c, r2, c2) {
  if (r == r2 && c == c2) {
     if (r == 0 && r2 == 0) {
         getActiveEditor().beginEditing();
         getActiveEditor().enableFullEditMode();   
     }
   }
 }
```