# How to enable edit on single tap with Handsontable using a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, mobile, handsontable

I'm trying to get the editor to open on a single tap of a cell in handsontable using a mobile device. The current functionality requires the user to double-tap the cell to enable editing, but my requirement is to have this work when the user selects the cell with a single tap.

I searched and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18304026/when-using-handsontable-how-to-force-a-selected-cell-into-edit-mode) which goes some way to helping. When I use the following code the editor behaves the way I want it to when using a single mouse click, but fails to fire on a touch event:

```
Handsontable.hooks.add( 'afterSelectionEnd', function() {
        this.getActiveEditor().beginEditing();
    });
```

Looking through the handsontable code it looks like the 'afterSelectionEnd' hook is triggered by mouse events but not touch events. I'm hoping there's a solution that doesn't involve modifying the original source, but at the moment I'm not having any luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can fire the afterSelectionEnd hook manually using an event listener for the touchend event.

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchend', function(event){
    Handsontable.hooks.run(hot, 'afterSelectionEnd');
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLcx2aa7/13/)